# define dictionary in Python like they do in Ruby

Tags: python

I need to convert this Ruby code to Python:

```
dicts = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

I'm new to Python and never learned Ruby. But I read some documentations and I think in Python this should look something like this:

```
dicts = {}.setdefault(k, [])
```

But I'm not sure. Could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 2):

From the Ruby docs:

```
# While this creates a new default object each time
h = Hash.new { |hash, key| hash[key] = "Go Fish: #{key}" }
h["c"]           #=> "Go Fish: c"
h["c"].upcase!   #=> "GO FISH: C"
h["d"]           #=> "Go Fish: d"
h.keys           #=> ["c", "d"]
```

So the python equivalent for your scenario is to use `defaultdict` in the following way:

```
from collections import defaultdict

dicts = defaultdict(list)
print(dicts['any_key']) #[]
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply `{'k': []}` gives you a dictionary where `'k'` maps to an empty list.